# HP Fortify flagging Cross site Request Forgery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csrf

We are sending a request to the server using AJAX. The code snippet for the request is

```
    var getURL = url + mediaAPI + "personId=" + person_id + "&encounterId=" + encntr_id;
    restAPIClient.open("GET", getURL, false);
    window.location = "javascript:MPAGES_SVC_AUTH(restAPIClient)";
    restAPIClient.send(null);

    if (restAPIClient.readyState === 4 && restAPIClient.status === 200) {
        var mediaReply = JSON.parse(restAPIClient.responseText);
```

HP Fortify is flagging the line `"restAPIClient.open("GET", getURL, false);"` as ***cross site request forgery*** issue.

Can anyone help me out on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: why `window.location` is there in the code?

Comment: Here we are requesting a xml file from "CAMM WAS" server. XML files stores in that archive. So we are giving that path here to fetch from there.

Comment: Here is the another code snippet in which we are not using window.location
var sendVal = "^MINE^, " + codeSet + ".0";
   if(CERN_BrowserDevInd){
    var url = "MP_GET_CODESET?parameters=" + sendVal;
    info.open('GET', url, async);
    info.send(null);
   }